# Interpreting base 64 in C# from an image based via JSON/PHP (base64_encode)

Tags: c#, php, json, base64

So I'm able to read an image file successfully, and pass it back to my C# application but I'm unable to decode it properly.

I'm returning the JSON data as such (the json_encode function isn't shown) via PHP:

```
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));

        if ( strlen($imgbinary) > 0 ){
            return array("success"=>true, "map"=>base64_encode($imgbinary));
        }
```

Then in C# I use Newtonsoft.Json to decode the string (I can read success and the map properties successfully), but I'm unable to then use base64 decode to properly write the image to a file (or to display).

I'm doing it as such:

```
File.WriteAllText(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\MyDir\\" + FileName, Base64Decode(FileData));

    public string Base64Decode(string data)
    {
        byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(binary);
    }
```

Am I missing something crazy simple here?  What is really strange is after I decode the data, the file size is LARGER than the original file.  (I realize once you encode, data increases by about 33%, just strange that after I then decode, it is still larger).

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Don't write it as a TEXT file but as a binary file by saving the byte array directly to file (don't do the Encoding.Default.GetString)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Am I missing something crazy simple here?

Yes. An image *isn't* a text file, so you shouldn't be using `File.WriteAllText`. What *characters* do you believe are present in an image file? It's really, really important to distinguish between when your data is fundamentally text, and when it's fundamentally binary. If you try to treat either as if it were the other, you're asking for trouble.

*Don't* convert back from the byte array to text (your `Encoding.Default.GetString` call will be losing data) - just use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Convert.FromBase64String(data));
```

Comment: Possible typo: "should be using File.WriteAllText". I think you mean "shouldn't" :)