# How do you download an attachment from JSON data using C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I'm new to RestAPI and JSON and I want to know if it is possible to download files from JSON. I'm working on a site call OnTime. The sample code they provide is written in C#. When I do an api call with their code to look up items with attachments this is the format I get back.

```
OK

{
    "data": [
        {
            "attach_date": "2014-08-27T18:18:54Z",
            "id": 37,
            "created_by_id": 100,
            "created_by_user_type": 0,
            "description": "",
            "file_name": "cpuz-setup.exe",
            "source_id": 2,
            "source_type": 0,
            "file_data": null,
            "data_hash": "0nW/Gi69l9o9Aw6MEvddCw=="
        }
    ]
}
```

I've seen other articles and blogs that say the JSON will provide a url to the file in the JSON. So what I would like to know is there a way to download the following file from this JSON code?

If so can you provide links to examples or sample codes in C# if possible?

Comment: You have the file name provided to you (cpuz-setup.exe), along with other pieces of information. But the file is presumably on a relative path on the client file system.  C#/server will not be able to create this file without some kind of byte stream or another representation of the file's bytes.

Comment: if file_data actually contained the base64 encoded binary data from within the file, then you can simply parse the json, extract the file_data variable, decode base64, and store the resulting binary in another file, effectively achieving a 'download'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421075/interpreting-base-64-in-c-sharp-from-an-image-based-via-json-php-base64-encode as it has an example and may be helpful.